# Why is the jQuery selector, ("parent > child"), skipping children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out why it looks like my selector is skipping children.  I'm pretty sure it's due to my not fully understanding the ("parent > child") selector, but I don't know what more I could do to better understand this short of asking someone.  I've been reading the jQuery documentation, searching Google and searching stackoverflow.  I've found information on the selector in question, but nothing seems to answer my question.

Please check out the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/49kboqze/

and here's my jQuery code:

```
if($("div.thumbdiv").length)  {

$("a.thumblink").each(function(index) {
    var $href = $(this).attr("href");
    var $title = $(this).attr("title");
    var $alt = $(this).find($("img.thumbnail")).attr("alt");

    $(this).parents("div.imggallery > div").css("outline", "solid red 1px");

});

}
```

When I run the following code:

```
var parentEls = $(this).parents()
        .map(function() {
         return $(this).attr("class");
         })
        .get()
        .join( ", " );

    console.log(  parentEls );
```

it returns all of the element's parent's classes.  I am 100% sure, because of this, that the div with a class of thumbdiv is it's immediate parent, and it's "grandparent" is a div with the class of imggallery.  So far everything seems to make sense both in my head, and in practice.  Here's where I have to throw my hands up though; thumbdiv has a couple of siblings, one of which is directly above it, the div with a class of mainimgdiv.  mainimgdiv is a child of imggallery as well and, in fact, it's first child.  So I can't understand for the life of me why, when I reach the parent div.imggallery and then use a selector from that point, that it skips it's first child and goes back down to it's second child, div.thumbdiv.  That's not even where $(this) is (this being a.thumblink, which is the only child of div.thumbdiv).

I thought it may have something to do with the .each function, so I tried using the selector outside of the conditional and it still acted the same way.

I'm at a loss and I can't seem to figure this out.  What am I missing here?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Which element(s) are you actually *trying* to select? I would expect `$(this).parents("div.imggallery > div")` to select only the `thumbdiv` that is a parent of the clicked anchor.

Comment: oops...I forgot to mention that specifically.  I mentioned it, but it wasn't strait forward.  I'm trying to select the div with a class of mainimgdiv, which is a child of div.imggallery.  It's actually the first child also so I thought it would select it if I specified it, or list it as one of it's children if I asked for all children that are divs.

Comment: OK. You didn't actually ask for all of imggallery's children though. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you have this:

```
$(this).parents("div.imggallery > div")
```

...what you are saying is "select all of the ancestors of `this` element which also happen to match the selector `"div.imggallery > div"`".

Your `mainimgdiv` div is *not* an ancestor of the `this` element, your anchor, so it is *not* included in the selection. In other words, it is not your selector that is "skipping" the children, it is the fact that you used `.parents()`.

If your intention is to get from the clicked link to that `mainimgdiv` via DOM navigation then you could do this:

```
$(this).closest("div.imggallery").find(".mainimgdiv")
```

That is, use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to navigate *up* through the tree to the ancestor `imggallery`, then from there use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to navigate back down to the `mainimgdiv` element.

Comment: That was a beautiful explanation and my headache is gone and replaced with a light bulb that just clicked on haha.  Thank you so much!  I feel stupid, but relieved...I'm still learning though, so I guess I get a free pass.  I ended up using the .find selector with the .parents selector like so [$(this.parents("div.imggallery").find("img.mainimg")] and that works, but using .closest looks like it might be cleaner so I'm going to change it .  Thank you very much again!

Comment: `.closest()` is almost always a more logical choice than `.parents()`, because (in my experience, anyway) it is rare to want to select multiple ancestors at different levels in the tree all at once. Note that `.closest()` only navigates up, it doesn't select nearby siblings or anything even though the word "closest" implies that it might. By the way, does your page have more than one image gallery on it? If not you don't need to muck around with all this `.closest().find()` stuff, you can just select the div directly with `$(".mainimgdiv")`.

Comment: funny you should mention that about the image gallery ^-^  The entire thing used to (used to meaning earlier today) actually use id's because there was only meant to be one gallery on any given page.  However, I realized that on one page, it would potentially be used multiple times @.@  so I am having to redo, rework, and rethink several things.  I think I have it working somewhat now, but it's setting the mainimg to the very last thumbnail from the .each function.  It's supposed to be the first thumbnail...but that's another issue all together :p

Answer (score 1):

Simply said, jQuery selectors are modelled after CSS selectors.

```
$(".parent > .child")
```

The above would select immediate children, but not children of children.

Have a look at this demo: http://jsbin.com/duhadikiji/edit?html,js,output

Comment: div.mainimgdiv is an immediate child of div.imggallery though.  It's right below it, the first child, in fact.  Dreamweaver even has it structured as it's immediate child.  Or at least I'm pretty sure it's an immediate child.